# Add two factor authentication to my web application

Tags: java, spring, two-factor-authentication

I have a java spring web application and currently it has a normal authentication flow. I need to add a two factor authentication implementation to it. For that can we use 3rd party provider like google or any other provider.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: @ JeffC read a lot but couldn't find a solution. Finally decided to post to stackoverflow to get a help.At least if I can get an simple guide or starting point will be able to go ahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to add a two factor authentication implementation to [my java spring web application].

Here's a [good package that I wrote](https://github.com/j256/java-two-factor-auth) which implements 2FA/two-factor authentication in Java code.

Copying from the READ_ME, to get this to work you:

1. Properly seed the random number generator.
2. Use `generateBase32Secret()` to generate a secret key for a user.
3. Store the secret key in the database associated with the user account.
4. Display the QR image URL returned by `qrImageUrl(...)` to the user.
5. User uses the image to load the secret key into his authenticator application.

Whenever the user logs in:

1. The user enters the number from the authenticator application into the login form.
2. Read the secret associated with the user account from the database.
3. The server compares the user input with the output from `generateCurrentNumber(...)`.
4. If they are equal then the user is allowed to log in.

Comment: How is this solution different from commercial offerings like the ones provided by Stormpath?

Comment: Uh, it's free and open source?  Otherwise I'm not sure @PradeepKumarTR.

Comment: The only thing I really dislike is that you are saving the private keys in a database...

Comment: Geez @DamirOlejar.  It was just an example.  How do you think it works in reality?

Comment: @Gray, sorry but I was looking for a final solution. What do you suggest that we should do ? I am thinking about using the AES and storing the private key in the config, then saving the encrypted version in DB.  Still having doubts about it.

Comment: Also, not sure if this will work with all user time-zones... would it ??